# Interpret MaltParser output

Tags: java, output, malt-parser

I am using MaltParser and I finally got it running but now I got some doubts about the output. The output that I receive is the following.

```
 Frase numero 6
   Precisa de uma renovação ao nível dos quartos.
    1 [I:0(0->1 DEPREL:STA )][O:2,4,8,9]ID:01 FORM:Precisa LEMMA:precisar CPOSTAG:v POSTAG:v-fin FEATS:_ 
    2 [I:1(1->2 DEPREL:SC )][O:]ID:11 FORM:de LEMMA:de CPOSTAG:prep POSTAG:prep FEATS:_ 
    3 [I:4(4->3 DEPREL:>N )][O:]ID:21 FORM:uma LEMMA:um CPOSTAG:art POSTAG:art FEATS:_ 
    4 [I:1(1->4 DEPREL:SUBJ )][O:3]ID:31 FORM:renovação LEMMA:renovação CPOSTAG:n POSTAG:n FEATS:_ 
    5 [I:8(8->5 DEPREL:>N )][O:]ID:41 FORM:ao LEMMA:ao CPOSTAG:prepxdet POSTAG:prepxdet FEATS:_ 
    6 [I:8(8->6 DEPREL:>N )][O:]ID:51 FORM:nível LEMMA:nível CPOSTAG:adj POSTAG:adj FEATS:_ 
    7 [I:8(8->7 DEPREL:>N )][O:]ID:61 FORM:dos LEMMA:do CPOSTAG:pron POSTAG:pron-det FEATS:_ 
    8 [I:1(1->8 DEPREL:ACC )][O:5,6,7]ID:71 FORM:quartos LEMMA:quarto CPOSTAG:n POSTAG:n FEATS:_ 
    9 [I:1(1->9 DEPREL:PUNC )][O:]ID:81 FORM:. LEMMA:. CPOSTAG:punc POSTAG:punc FEATS:_
```

My objective is to understand how the words are connected I understand that **I: 0** is the root of the sentence, but I don't understand what are the other id for. I think this ** [O: 3] ** means that the word 4 it connected to root and word 3 but I don't understand what **1->4** should mean.

What I want to know is, for example word 8, it is a name I want to know what other words are directly connected to him.

Thanks